# Number of elements in Char array

Tags: c++

How can I get the size of char array if I define the size but put less elements

```
#define N 100

char a[N];
cin >> a;
```

supoose I enter 126,
then what do i do to get the number of elemens (3 in this case) in this array now

Comment: I think you mean `cin >> a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strlen()` which returns the number of characters in char array.Check my solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#define N 100

using namespace std;

int main()
{

 char a[N];

 cout << "Enter number: ";
 cin >> a;

 cout << "Length: " << strlen(a);
}
```

Comment: `#include <cstring>` and `cout << "Length: " << strlen(a)`.

Comment: Why did you cast it to unsigned? `printf("Length: %zu", strlen(a));`

Comment: @Ayxan C99 compiler supports `%zu`, i prefer to use `%lu` because it's most widely used..

Comment: @MariosNikolaou - So you prefer printing the result of `strlen()` in a way that gives undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Peter it gives undefined behaviour?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou - When `printf()` is given an argument with type different from the corresponding format specifier, its behaviour is undefined.  Such as a format specifier for `long unsigned` and a corresponding argument that is possibly not `long unsigned`.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Those docs are wrong.   According to the standard the `strlen()` function returns `size_t`, which is an implementation-defined unsigned type, not a signed integral type.

Comment: @Peter it's ok now?

Comment: That's fine.   Looks like you've realised why iostreams (which are type safe) are often preferred in C++ over C I/O.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged with `C++`, I would first suggest using `std::string` instead of `char` array. Furthermore, use `std::getline` in order to fill out declared `std::string` with user's input. Then the code would look like the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string a;
    std::getline(std::cin, a);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Length: " << a.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```